# How to add a watermark to an SVG image for security purposes

Tags: html, web, svg, watermark

we want to add watermarks to our SVG-Images to secure them from criminals. 
So just adding an image as a background for the SVG does not solve our problem.

Does anyone know a software or method to cryptonize such a watermark into an SVG? 
I think about a software that cuts the watermark image into multiple randomly cuts (polygons) and set them randomly inside the SVG on different positions.

I would be happy if someone could give me hints or help.

Thanks 
Christian

Comment: Given that SVG is a text format, anything you add can just as easily be excised.

Answer (score -4):

If you want to add a watermark to your SVG-image, you need to select the SVG-image. Then click on the 'Add Photos' button and select from your computer which image you want to watermark. Then go to the Advanced Tab and select Add Effect/Annotation, then Authoring and then Watermark. Here you can add one and press Save.

Comment: Hi Kevin, in which software is this possible?

Comment: At least mention which app that we should use